# How to combine for loops?

Tags: django, templates, loops, for-loop

I'm making an HTML template in Django. For a list of animals and a range of numbers, I'd like to do something like this:

```
{% for animal in AnimalList and i in range%}
<p>{{i} {{animal.type}} </p>
{%endfor%}
```

but i get a template syntax error when i try something like that. The range could be from 6-10 or 3-7; the range's start and end points depend on some other functions that have happened elsewhere in the code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use {forloop.counter} to get the times the loop has been entered and use the value from that other functions to increment this value.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use two loops?

```
{% for animal in AnimalList %}
    {% for i in range %}
        <p>{{i} {{animal.type}} </p>
    {%endfor%}
{%endfor%}
```

Comment: Depends on the output he want to get. @Bob What do you need? A numbered list of animals?